# Facebook login script doesn't auto-populate fields

Tags: java, facebook, authentication

When I run my code everything works fine, but the email and password fields are not auto-populated.

My Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

System.out.println("http://www.facebook.com"+driver.getTitle());

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
System.out.println("Successfully opened the website");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("umeshy2009@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("Annik3");
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
System.out.println("Successfully logged in");
//Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
//Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log out")).click();
System.out.println("Successfully logged out");
driver.quit();
```

Comment: Using any such automation is against Facebook’s ToS. If you want to interact with users, pages or content on Facebook - use their API.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't your real account....

maybe a "wait" is needed. After the maximize it starts typing.. can be it is to fast.

Comment: Maybe it is time to change your password?

Comment: Dont worry bro...its not correct passowrd which is mentioned in script....i need solutions

Comment: Did you add a delay between the maximize and the sendkey?

Comment: I assume it dind't help then... FB does have api's that you can use. Are other elements found correctly? (btw, I get logged on automatically when I go to facebook, that can be an option to, use chrome ;-) )